# Using References module, is it possible to only show nodes created by the logged in user in select list?

Tags: 7, nodes

I made a node reference field and it gives me a select list of all the nodes of a specific content type. However I only want the select list to show the nodes made by the logged in user. Is there any way to set conditions some way?

Comment: Wasn't a node reference 6 module? Why not Entity reference?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the references module

https://drupal.org/project/references

Comment: No problem, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: You should check the permission for that content type to allow:"View own content"

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) which return the list of all node title created by the user & then use [View reference](https://drupal.org/project/viewreference) module to have field calling that.